# Object filtering issue after removing a field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My previous query is

```
    queryset_list = Team.objects.filter(
        models.Q(players=self.request.user) |
        models.Q(team_manager=self.request.user) | models.Q(coach=self.request.user)         ).order_by('id').distinct()
```

Now I have remove the "players" field from the table "Team"

This change is only for the new update.... But I need to provide support for both newly updated users and previously updated users.....

Now if a person login with old update this will crack

Answer (score 0):

For this reason we provide with api versioning. `site-name/api/v1/` and `site-name/api/v2`, any major changes to the api are handled using that, however minor changes like that can be done based on when the user was added, provided you stored the `created_on` timestamp for all users.

```py
if self.request.user.created_on > API_DATE_CHANGE:
    return NEW_API-- filter here and return new values here.

return OLD_API-- filter and return old values here
```

Comment: This is not for the created user...

I will explain.....

Comment: I am having a list API.... 

In older build we are displaying the teams object if a person is associated with player field or coach filed or team_manager field

Comment: Now this player field is not there ....It will removed from the team .....

Comment: Then how will you support both if you've already removed the field?